# Docker Symfony can't connect to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, symfony, docker, docker-compose

Error occured while trying to access Postgresql database:

```
(6/6) ConnectionException
    An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "db" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

i didnt add the database name in docker-compose.yml because i want to create it using the console. i tried changing the port to 5432, so it tells me the databse pfe does not exist, so when im trying to create it the command line i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: db
    database_port: 5433
    database_name: pfe
    database_user: admin
    database_password: admin
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:  

  front:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    links:
      - "engine:engine"
    volumes:
      - ".:/home/docker:ro"
      - "./docker/front/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"

  engine:
    build: ./docker/engine/
    volumes:
      - ".:/home/docker:rw"
      - "./docker/engine/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    working_dir: "/home/docker"

  db:
    image: camptocamp/postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=admin"
      - "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of the anwser, if i type `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`, it will run the php natively installed in my computer wich it doesnt know the db host declared in docker-compose.yml. Thats why we need to execute the php runing in docker.
So in my case this will be:

```
docker-compose exec engine bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

> This is only a part of the anwser and the app is working fine with the port 5432, but i want to use another port and i need help.